# Write down the system of equations for obtaining the general equation of surfaces orthogonal to the family of equations $x(x^2+y^2+z^2)=cxy$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Write down the system  of equations for obtaining the general equation of surfaces orthogonal to the family of equations
> $$
> x(x^2+y^2+z^2) = cxy 
> $$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure it is not asking for a family of *curves* orthogonal to these given surfaces? (I think surfaces perpendicular to surfaces have degrees of freedom left, all kinds of harmonica-shaped solutions would seem to be possible and give you infinitely many solutions).